# Late row lookup with a complex SQL request

Tags: mysql

I have a list that can be filtered (multiple filter), paginated and the original resulting sql is :

```
SELECT 
    b0_.id AS id0,
    b0_.offset AS offset1,
    b0_.title AS title2,
    b0_.message AS message3,
    b0_.type AS type4,
    b0_.resolved_at AS resolved_at5,
    b0_.operationImport_id AS operationImport_id6
FROM
    bank_import_error b0_
        INNER JOIN
    bank_operation_import b1_ ON b0_.operationImport_id = b1_.id
        INNER JOIN
    bank_account b2_ ON b1_.account_id = b2_.id
WHERE
    b2_.company_id = 1
        AND (b1_.started_at LIKE '%03%'
        OR b0_.title LIKE '%03%'
        OR b2_.name LIKE '%03%'
        OR b0_.offset LIKE '%03%')
ORDER BY b1_.started_at ASC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 70
```

This request take 3,5 to 4 minutes so I tried to apply the "late row lookups" technique to it :

```
SELECT    b.id as id0,    b.offset as offset1,    b.title as title2,   b.message as message3,    b.type as type4,    b.resolved_at as resolver_at5,    b.operationImport_id as operationImport_id6 FROM 
    (SELECT 
        b0.id
    FROM
        (SELECT id, operationImport_id FROM bank_import_error WHERE title LIKE '%03%' OR offset LIKE '%03%') b0
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT id, account_id, started_at FROM bank_operation_import WHERE started_at LIKE '%03%') b1 ON b0.operationImport_id = b1.id
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT id from bank_account WHERE name like '%03%' AND company_id = 1) b2 ON b1.account_id = b2.id      ORDER BY B1.started_at ASC
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET 70 
    ) o INNER JOIN bank_import_error b on b.id = o.id
```

But this second request doesn't give the same results. An ordering problem ? A logical problem ? What can I do to solve this ?

Environment : Mysql, InnoDB.
SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4157/1/0
But the informations are sensitive so i don't put data in the tables for now.

Comment: Is there an index on `started_at`? You need an index so that ordering by that column will be efficient.

Comment: Yes, there is. The second request is fast and take only a few seconds ...but it returns bad results.

Comment: The only difference I can see is that the second query doesn't include the `started_at` column in the results. The rest of the results should be the same. Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Sorry there isn't started_at in the first request, it was just a test. I edited my post.

Comment: Now there's no difference between the two queries at all. What do you mean by "late row lookup"?

Comment: That technique is explained here : http://explainextended.com/2011/02/11/late-row-lookups-innodb/

Comment: I found that when I googled it myself. But you're not doing that. There's no subquery in your code.

Comment: I'm tired this morning, it's edited.  Now you see my query with subrequest.

Answer (score 0):

Late row lookup requires that you write an efficient subquery that gets the IDs of the subset of rows, and join that with the rest of the query.

```
SELECT 
   b0_.id AS id0,
   b0_.offset AS offset1,
   b0_.title AS title2,
   b0_.message AS message3,
   b0_.type AS type4,
   b0_.resolved_at AS resolved_at5,
   b0_.operationImport_id AS operationImport_id6
FROM
   bank_import_error b0_
       INNER JOIN
   bank_operation_import b1_ ON b0_.operationImport_id = b1_.id
       INNER JOIN
   bank_account b2_ ON b1_.account_id = b2_.id
       INNER JOIN
   (SELECT id
    FROM bank_operation_import
    ORDER BY started_at ASC
    LIMIT 10 OFFSET 70) AS b3_ ON b1_.id = b3_.id
WHERE
   b2_.company_id = 1
       AND (b1_.started_at LIKE '%03%'
       OR b0_.title LIKE '%03%'
       OR b2_.name LIKE '%03%'
       OR b0_.offset LIKE '%03%')
ORDER BY b1_.started_at ASC
```

However, this won't return the same data as the original query, because you're filtering **after** you select the limited rows.

I don't think it's possible to make good use of late row lookup in a query like yours, because you need to do the filtering before paging, and the filtering is the expensive part (because `LIKE '%03%'` can't be indexed).

Comment: Ok so is there another technique that i can use ? The technique showed in these slides http://fr.slideshare.net/slideshow/view?login=Eweaver&preview=no&slideid=1&title=efficient-pagination-using-mysql needs triggers that are, i think, not easy to maintain/debug.